# how to append a hash code to the same file from which it is calculated in c#

Tags: c#, file, encryption, hash

i want to append the hash code to the file from which it is computed.(the file can be of any format)and then encrypt the result using RSA algorithm. and now i want to decrypt the encrypted result and compute the hash for the original file. now i have to compare the two hash codes.... can any one help me please
   thanks in advance

Comment: No, I don't think this is possible, as you would have to compensate for the change in hash value.

Comment: @nonnb: It would be possible if you calculate the hash code from the part of the decrypted data that is not the appended hash code.

Comment: @Guffa fair enough, but either way, there would have to be an agreed protocol where the recipient knew where to remove the hash from the file. Alternative would be to use a composite file format, e.g. Zip both the file and a separate hash into a new file.

Answer (score 0):

This is very possible. This is how [Microsoft Authenticode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537359%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) works, for example. As @Guffa says above, there needs to be some defined format in the file to separate the digital signature (signed hash) from the part that is hashed. A simple example may be to embed the digital signature in a [certain XML element in an XML file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229745.aspx) using the [SignedXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.signedxml.aspx) class, for example. More complex examples may use multipart files, as @nonnb said. The signer and verifier need to know where to find the signature and what to include from the calculation.